# UPDATE PANEL question

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a code that generates a new question based on question type and updates the asp.net update panel with a new question every time user clicks next button My question is how do I get the response of the question user is currently on when I click next. More specifically how do I read previous value from update panel as a next is clicked and a new panel is loaded.

```
    public static int incremental = 0; 
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        UpdateButton2.Text = "Start the Pre-Assessment";

    }

    protected void UpdateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        COPDEntities1 copdContext = new COPDEntities1();
        UpdateButton2.Text = "NEXT"; 
        var questions = (from p in copdContext.Questions select p).ToList();
        if (incremental == questions.Count)
            {
                incremental = 0; 

             }

            DateTimeLabel2.Text = questions[incremental].QuestionText;

            if (questions[incremental].QuestionAnswerTypeID == 1)
            {
                RadioButtonList choices = new RadioButtonList();
                choices.ID = "choices";

                choices.ID = Convert.ToString(1);
                choices.Items.Add(new ListItem("True", "0"));
                choices.Items.Add(new ListItem("False", "1"));
                pnlChoice.Controls.Add(choices);
            }
            if (questions[incremental].QuestionAnswerTypeID == 2)
            {
                TextBox text = new TextBox();
                text.ID = "choices";
                pnlChoice.Controls.Add(text);


            }
            if (questions[incremental].QuestionAnswerTypeID == 3)

            {
                int questID = questions[incremental].QuestionID;
                var responses = (from r in copdContext.QuestionResponses where r.QuestionID == questID select r).ToList();

                RadioButtonList choices = new RadioButtonList();
                choices.ID = "choices";
                choices.ID = Convert.ToString(3);
                foreach(var choice in responses)
                {     
                      int choiceID= choice.ResponseID;
                      var multchoices = (from c in copdContext.Responses where c.ResponseID == choiceID select c).FirstOrDefault();
                      choices.Items.Add(new ListItem(multchoices.ResponseLongdescription, Convert.ToString(multchoices.ResponseID)));

                }




                pnlChoice.Controls.Add(choices);
               // Label1.Text = Convert.ToString(responses[0].ResponseID); 


            }
            if (questions[incremental].QuestionAnswerTypeID == 4)
            {
                int questID = questions[incremental].QuestionID;
                var responses = (from r in copdContext.QuestionResponses where r.QuestionID == questID select r).ToList();

                CheckBoxList choices = new  CheckBoxList();
                choices.ID = "choices";
                choices.ID = Convert.ToString(3);
                foreach (var choice in responses)
                {
                    int choiceID = choice.ResponseID;
                    var multchoices = (from c in copdContext.Responses where c.ResponseID == choiceID select c).FirstOrDefault();
                    choices.Items.Add(new ListItem(multchoices.ResponseLongdescription, Convert.ToString(multchoices.ResponseID)));

                }
                pnlChoice.Controls.Add(choices);
            }
            if (questions[incremental].QuestionAnswerTypeID == 5)
            {
                TextBox text = new TextBox();
                text.ID = "choices";
                pnlChoice.Controls.Add(text);

            }
            if (questions[incremental].QuestionAnswerTypeID == 6)
            {


            }
            if (questions[incremental].QuestionAnswerTypeID == 7)
            {
                RadioButtonList choices = new RadioButtonList();


            }
            incremental++; 

    }
}
```

Comment: FYI, You don't need to put "ASP C#" in your title - that's what we have tags for on [SO]. Also, it's "ASP.NET", not "ASP".

Answer (score 0):

Don't create radio or checkbox when button is clicked. Create them in VS Page designer or preinit, otherwise it wont be stored in viewstate and you wont be able to get it. Once controls are created in dsigner or preinit, show / hide / set the values them based on your question type. This way you can get the values of previous controls (basically current controls). Otherwise you can get the data using tradition requst["id"] way, but this will be messy.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dynamically creating the controls and adding them to the panel, try using a MultiView and defining all possible views:

```
<asp:MultiView id="MyMultiView" runat="server">
   <asp:View id="FirstView" runat="server">
   <!-- Markup for the first view -->
   </asp:View>
   <asp:View id="SecondView" runat="server">
   <!-- Markup for the second view -->
   </asp:View>
   <asp:View id="ThirdView" runat="server">
   <!-- Markup for the third view -->
   </asp:View>
</asp:MultiView>
```

Then from the code-behind on the button click event switch active views to the one you want. This way you'll be able to grab the value of any control whether it's in an active view or not.